Cannot boot Ubuntu in a dual boot
I have a dual boot config Windows 11 + Ubuntu 24.10, with Secure Boot enabled. Recently I cannot boot in Ubuntu. First I had this error:
Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Volume Corrupt
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Volume Corrupt
start_image() returned Volume Corrupt

I booted from a USB drive. I executed a file fsck and fixed the efi partition, and then I copied 2 files from the USB on my drive: grubx64.efi and another .efi file.
Now my error is:
Invalid image
Failed to read header: Invalid Parameter
Failed to load images: Invalid Parameter
start_img() returned Invalid Parameter

More details here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xtPF5RNwsZ/
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,2)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    offsetio extcmd macho elf file gettext boot bufio verifiers crypto 
    terminal normal datetime date mmap drivemap blocklist archelp newc 
    vga_text relocator video chain ntldr search_label search_fs_file 
    search_fs_uuid search keylayouts at_keyboard pci usb usb_keyboard gcry_md5 
    hashsum gcry_crc gzio xzio lzopio lspci fshelp ext2 xfs acpi reboot 
    iso9660 gcry_sha1 div udf exfat font diskfilter raid6rec zstd btrfs ventoy 
    read halt video_fb vbe linux linux16 test true sleep echo bitmap gfxterm 
    bitmap_scale trig video_colors gfxmenu videotest videoinfo functional_test 
    videotest_checksum video_cirrus video_bochs vga minicmd help configfile tr 
    biosdisk disk ls tar zfs squash4 pbkdf2 gcry_sha512 password_pbkdf2 
    all_video png jpeg part_gpt part_msdos fat ntfs loopback 
    gfxterm_background procfs gfxterm_menu smbios
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       btrfs
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p8: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p9: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       exfat
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sda1: /dev/sda1 already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda2 and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] from Intel Corporation NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.10, oracular, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: X7400PC.303(5.19) from American Megatrends International, LLC.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0003,0004,0005,0006
Boot0001* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,d4257504-27b5-4787-9625-4f89e87a164b,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,d4257504-27b5-4787-9625-4f89e87a164b,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000000000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0004* UEFI OS   HD(8,GPT,9ef4a1a8-3f22-4b3f-9889-47a1161f0067,0x5e14c000,0x200000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)0000424f
Boot0005* Windows Boot Manager  HD(8,GPT,9ef4a1a8-3f22-4b3f-9889-47a1161f0067,0x5e14c000,0x200000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)0000424f
Boot0006* UEFI: VerbatimSTORE N GO 1100, Partition 2    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(12,0)/HD(2,MBR,0x74cd7c2d,0x3a88000,0x10000)0000424f

   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
6c4ec35ced47a0bfa4cc96d3570d2e17   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
9f09ebdacbdc7c46269f99c7754bbfd3   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
9f09ebdacbdc7c46269f99c7754bbfd3   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
211a377300f24895b42f5ce384344a0c   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
23837e7f81b5b729c2cc673d3da56273   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
17b3fa127f74e0189c6192a80c3fe28f   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
3134a3c759cae87284e8e37d6b841318   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
b8796e68099026aabcebb8fcf75b21f6   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi
d32b1a522d11d5680bfc6d9956d770a6   nvme0n1p8/Pop_OS-0023a195-eb1d-4878-9dfa-4e33cc4d2ed6/vmlinuz-previous.efi
f4e969e0c2162c53fd1106fdcdc1332b   nvme0n1p8/Pop_OS-0023a195-eb1d-4878-9dfa-4e33cc4d2ed6/vmlinuz.efi
cbdee8bcb38ceff4b1e77385bffe6757   nvme0n1p8/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi
226dd35eecb9c94a5e2f6defe862645a   nvme0n1p8/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
e8202499ef13b06fdda52341f8e5362e   nvme0n1p8/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
cbdee8bcb38ceff4b1e77385bffe6757   nvme0n1p8/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p6   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p8   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
mapper/vtoy_persistent  : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p7   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p6   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p8   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, exfat
mapper/vtoy_persistent  : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, 
nvme0n1p7   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, btrfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p8   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
mapper/vtoy_persistent  : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
nvme0n1p7   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: BE0D5CCA-813D-4F8E-A672-59EE3EC60396
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3     567296  529840782  529273487 252.4G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4  529842176 1578418175 1048576000   500G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p5 1997848576 1999998975    2150400     1G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p6 1999998976 2000408575     409600   200M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p7 1580515328 1647624190   67108863    32G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p8 1578418176 1580515327    2097152     1G EFI System
nvme0n1p9 1647624192 1664401406   16777215     8G Linux swap
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x74cd7c2d
     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *        2048 61374463 61372416 29.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2       61374464 61439999    65536   32M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
Disk mapper/ventoy: 5.28 GiB, 5665497088 bytes, 11065424 sectors
Disk identifier: B179BD28-94FB-423E-9F95-94A26FD3742F
                      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
mapper/ventoy-part1       64 11054631 11054568  5.3G Microsoft basic data
mapper/ventoy-part2 11054632 11064759    10128  4.9M EFI System
mapper/ventoy-part3 11064760 11065359      600  300K Microsoft basic data
Disk mapper/vtoy_persistent: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Verbatim STORE N GO:;
1:1049kB:31.4GB:31.4GB:::boot;
2:31.4GB:31.5GB:33.6MB:fat16::esp;
mapper/ventoy:5665MB:dm:512:512:gpt:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:32.8kB:5660MB:5660MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:5660MB:5665MB:5186kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:5665MB:5665MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
mapper/vtoy_persistent:2147MB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:2147MB:2147MB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:HFM001TD3JX013N:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:271GB:271GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:271GB:808GB:537GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
8:808GB:809GB:1074MB:fat32:LINUX-UEFI:boot, esp;
7:809GB:844GB:34.4GB:btrfs::;
9:844GB:852GB:8590MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
5:1023GB:1024GB:1101MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
6:1024GB:1024GB:210MB:fat32:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

nvme0n1: 812696MiB:975512MiB:162816MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL      PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                               
├─sda1              exfat    4E21-0000                            74cd7c2d-01                          Ventoy     
│ ├─ventoy                                                                                                        
│ └─vtoy_persistent                                                                                               
└─sda2                                                                                                            
nvme0n1                                                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p1         vfat     58CD-765C                            d4257504-27b5-4787-9625-4f89e87a164b SYSTEM     EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                                       ae558e44-cade-4f7f-9b5f-e67b4c43e4d0            Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3         ntfs     D012CF2712CF1180                     90c63fd6-b740-4516-96ec-8173a5ee0dfa OS         Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4         ntfs     0A62BF2E62BF1D7F                     95d93d6a-63b1-41aa-b924-77862e31d351 Data       Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p5         ntfs     846CAF556CAF40B2                     716b46f6-08ab-4259-8aa0-9196273bd98c RECOVERY   Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p6         vfat     0AEA-9791                            bacbf54e-27c3-44b0-b11b-aa95605883dd MYASUS     Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p7         btrfs    ba9f7b76-79e3-44d9-ae1f-07e7f9fadae9 f32c4843-630f-4026-8530-47c2bb3a088d            
├─nvme0n1p8         vfat     303C-7CF4                            9ef4a1a8-3f22-4b3f-9889-47a1161f0067 LINUX-UEFI LINUX-UEFI
└─nvme0n1p9         swap     3f194546-bd8c-4d0a-ad90-e48701827e9d 3d8f9138-29cd-416d-b2aa-673cde7fdef1            

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                             Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ventoy               0 100% /cdrom
/dev/mapper/vtoy_persistent   1.2G  30% /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vtoy_persistent
/dev/nvme0n1p1                202M  21% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3               61.3G  76% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4               71.8G  86% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5              240.8M  77% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6              137.8M  30% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/nvme0n1p7                7.5G  74% /mnt
/dev/nvme0n1p8              749.2M  27% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8
efivarfs                        5K  92% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/ventoy          iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8
/dev/mapper/vtoy_persistent ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme0n1p1              vfat            ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3              fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4              fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p5              fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p6              vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p7              btrfs           rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/
/dev/nvme0n1p8              vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
ventoy
vtoy_persistent

================================= User choice ==================================

Is there RAID on this computer? no

mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix


If you have UEFI Secure boot on, you must boot with shimx64.efi, not grubx64.efi. My system never has had Secure boot on, and uses shimx64.efi. Since it is not just grub/shim, but kernel & all the boot files must be signed, you probably need to boot in UEFI mode with Secure boot on and totally reinstall grub, so shim & signed kernels are default.  Your UEFI boot entry 0001 shows shimx64.efi line 132. You also have a grub in gpt's protective MBR for old BIOS boot. Not sure with new system how you would ever get that, as it will not work with secure boot on and is not for UEFI boot.
